# Android requires context to Initialize a static variable

Tags: android, static, initialization, android-context

I need to store the value of "size" in a static variable.
The problem is: The class containing this code is a static class where I store variables and the idea was to execute this code just once, you can do it once per object but it means thousands of times (there are thousands of objects of a class that requires the value).
Is there any way to load the value just once as if it is a static block with the using the context value?

```
private static Point size;

public static float getProportion(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
}
```

Comment: You may save the values as `SharedPreferences`!

Comment: It is interesting, but in this case, how do I store it the first time?

Comment: Check your question again is it `with the using` or `without the using` ?

Comment: Why don't you just create a singleton?

Comment: I have considered the singleton, but it will be called one time per instance, the var is static in both sides (the class containing the initialization and the classes using it) so it means call this method a lot of times

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the size value to be initialised once, you can 'lazily' initialise it:

```
private static Point size = null;

public static Point getProportion(Context context) {
    if (size == null) {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
    }
    return size;
}
```

This still requires you to pass in a `Context` object. The only way around this is to have a static `Context`, which generally is a very bad idea, as static `Contexts` usually mean memory leaks (if the `Context` belongs to an `Activity` or `Service` which needs to be cleaned up throughout the lifetime of the app)

What you could do is create an `Application` class, and hold a static `Application` `Context`: (Psuedo code)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  public static Context context;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    this.context = this;
  }

}
```

Now you can use the static `Application` `Context` in `getProportion()`:

```
public static Point getProportion() {
    if (size == null) {
      WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)
                    MyApplication.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    ...
```

It's OK to have a static `Application` `Context` from a memory leak perspective, because this `Context` lives in the `Application` class of your app, meaning it lives for as long as your app does - it never needs to be cleaned up.

Don't forget to register your `Application` class in the manifest:

```
<manifest 
...
    <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am afraid the 'lazy' initialize is not an option, it should be called when the class loads

Comment: @DavidMarciel that's not possible. You don't have a context (or display size) at the time the class loads.